# how to access values of a (private) custom indicator in pinescript?

Tags: pine-script

I'm having a private custom indicator in pinescript. I can't see the source code (that's why it's private, I guess). For a strategy, I'd like to access the values of the indicator in pinescript. Is there a way to get the values of a custom indicator in PineScript? (I know there is for sma, ema etc, but it seems it's not there for all indicators, or is it?)
Thanks.

Comment: This question has already been asked, use the search.

Comment: I did search, couldn't find a clear answer, though. Can you point me to the answer?

Comment: Read this [article](https://www.tradingview.com/support/solutions/43000474048/).

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to access the code of private indicators in TradingView.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32004227)